# Enable (console) logging of router events in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Somewhere in my Vue and Vuex application I suspect a (Vue) router push is triggered. To debug this I would like to enable logging of some sort, see all routing events pass by in my console. How can I do this?

I've searched [the Vue Router guide](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/) for things like "logging", "events", and "console" but found nothing. In Angular I could just subscribe to all router events in a top level component, and I guess I'm looking for something similar.

So, in short: **how can you enable logging for Vue Router events?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to log the changes in the router-view.

So, in the component that has your `<router-view><router-view/>` tag, simply watch for router change:

```
watch: {
    '$route' (to, from) {
      console.log('Route changed from ' + from.path + ' to ' + to.path); 
    }
}
```

Let me know if this isn't you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You can suscribe to all router navigation. The keyword here is [navigation guard](https://v3.router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards). The right one for you would be `beforeEach`. You could do something like this in Vue Router 4 (in Vue Router 3 you would also have to call next):

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from) => {
  console.log({to, from})
})
```